# Are there instructions for removing or rebuilding the graphical interface?

Tags: unity, gui, gdm

Recently, I could not log in on a regular user desktop installation through the graphical login screen. However, I was able to successfully log in by switching (CTRL+ALT+F1) to terminal mode. Eventually, through the terminal mode I resolved the problem.

In researching my issue, on the Ubuntu forum; I noticed that there were numerous causes concerning the **inability** to use the graphical login screen. Which made finding the correct fix difficult. The simplest approach would seem to be a total "*tear-down*" of the graphical interface with a rebuild to resolve the login issue instead of spending a significant amount of time attempting to isolate a specific cause. Essentially applying a "*nuclear option*". After extensive research and numerous dead-ends; I found out my problem was caused by "*brltty*", but that is not my question.

**My question**: A listing of the packages that need to be removed so that Ubuntu simply boots into terminal mode (no graphical interface). Then a sequential listing of what packages need to be reinstalled to restore the graphical interface (which I assume are the same packages that were removed). Basically, a short tutorial on removing the graphical interface and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

To install without GUI, just install Ubuntu Server.

To add the GUI,

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I am referring to a **regular** desk-top installation where you can **no** longer login due to an error of some sort. You may have a raised a point that I overlooked by referencing 'sudo apt-get install unity' since I do not specifically recall uninstalling it and then re-installing it, which is why I was asking for a list of packages that need to be removed/reinstalled.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could try uninstalling `unity` and some other so-called metapackages and then `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was solved.  The reason for this request is to obtain a list of packages for future reference for those experiencing this issue in the future concerning what needs to be removed and then reinstalled. I saw quite a few users on the Ubuntu forum who had this issue, so it would be beneficial to provide one place for what needs to be removed and then reinstalled. I fumbled around till something finally worked. Your reference to _"unity"_ may have been one of those somethings that I had overlooked.